# How to use condition in maxInclusive restriction in xsd

Tags: xsd, schema

I am using schema version 1.0. I want to put condition on `maxInclusive`.

Like

- *if person selected minor(age<18) then in age textbox he should not be able to enter more than 18*
- *if he selected adult then we can have age limit till 123*

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with XSD when you work on a text box? Can you explain clearly what is your requirement.

Comment: I am just validating XML...in my app I have a UI which fill value of text box in xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<xs:element name="person">   
    <xs:element ref="age"/>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="age">
  <xs:alternative test="@PersonType='Age'" type="MinorAgeType"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@PersonType='Age'" type="AdultAgeType"/>
  <xs:alternative type="xs:error"/>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="MinorAgeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
       <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
       <xs:maxInclusive value="17"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="AdultAgeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
       <xs:minInclusive value="18"/>
       <xs:maxInclusive value="123"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Its also possible to achieve this by 'assert' but just like 'alternative' it is available in XML Schema 1.1
How can i achieve this in XML Schema 1.0